# Does it cost to retrieve objects from S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

S3 has a storage pricing some $ per GB. Do I get unlimited retrievals or Am I charged when I retrieve or download an object from S3 bucket?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@hephalump only mentioned data transfer costs in the answer. Just so you are aware, you are also charged for **object retrieval API calls**. The detailed S3 pricing is listed on [Amazon S3 pricing](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/) page. You can click the "Requests and data retrievals" tab and read the details.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you pay data transfer charges based on the amount of data transferred. As per the AWS documentation [here](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/):

> You pay for all bandwidth into and out of Amazon S3, except for the following:
>   - Data transferred in from the internet. 
>   - Data transferred out to an
>      Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud (Amazon EC2) instance, when the instance is in the same AWS Region as the S3 bucket.
>   - Data transferred out to
>      Amazon CloudFront (CloudFront).

Pricing varies based on the destination and volume but data transfer out to the Internet range from $0.00 on the free tier to $0.09/GB for the first 9.999TB/month.